# High CPU usage index.php?

Tags: server

We have use magento 1.8. My problem is down the website every evening ~ 7 to 8 PM  (IST). Our hosting team checked in the server, they said 150% + CPU usage of index.php.
But we cant identify the issue.

We have optimized and speedup for below things
1. Enable the gzip
2. db optimization
3. Disable log
4. Disable unused modules
5. Enable the Keepalive in httacess
6. Image expiry date

But we not get any solution. Please help.

Comment: Maybe Apache is not preforking correctly? Which PHP version do you use? Do you use a caching method? Is the Magento cache on? Is the MySQL slow log enabled? I think these things are important for your question.

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.33 , What is catching method? Where to anble mysql slow log

Answer (score 0):

The high usage of index.php is perfectly ok in general, as all requests use it as entry point.

If Your caches are active, and your database Server is similar in usage, then I dont see a problem.
But its possible, you have any modul or theme installed, which does cpu heavy work, so even with few users you get a lot of processing usage on php.

You should use general profiling technics or ask a dev experienced with profiling for further investigation.